# Word for the opposite of scheduled, repeating, or regular, as in a task or purchase

Tags: single-word-requests

> I just scraped my wall with a chair, so I added paint to my weekly shopping list as a ______ purchase.
>
> The other day I went to close up a bag of bread, and realized I was out of clothes pins, so I add a _______ purchase to my shopping list.
>
> I checked my shopping list for ________ items, and remembered that I wanted to get cookies for a snack later.

Some purchases happen on a scheduled, repeating basis -- e.g. weekly grocery shopping.

Other purchases happen on an irregular basis. They might be one time purchases (e.g. a socket wrench) or purchases that will repeat, but not in a scheduled way (e.g. command hooks, which will be purchased again at an indefinite time, such as next time you need to hang something up). They might be purchases which are motivated by an unexpected external need, or they might be motivated by whim of the purchaser (I feel like buying muffins today).

I am searching for an **adjective** to describe this second category of purchase.

Here are some words that are close, but which I feel do not capture the meaning I am attempting to convey:

**One-time** - the purchase might repeat, and even disregarding that, I feel that the category is not defined by whether or not the purchase repeats, but by the regularity of that repetition

**Irregular** - to me, this fails to capture the element of discretionary-ness and choice

**Sporadic** - again, I feel that this fails to capture the purposefulness that might be present, and instead implies a level of external chaos (like, if purchases just appear on your shopping list at random). I also perceive a connotation of scarcity in the term "sporadic", which does not necessarily apply to the category I am envisioning

You may disagree that one of the above words is not adequate. But if anyone's got further suggestions, I would, of course, appreciate the input.

Comment: 'One-off' would be idiomatic in this sense

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming things in programs is explicitly out of scope for our site according to our Help Center.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you explain a bit more why the words that you have already mentioned won't do? Why not use *irregular*? And you should know that singe-word requests are heavily regulated on this site: they are only allowed if they fulfil the conditions from the tag (hover over it).

Comment: @Cerberus I appreciate the advice on improving the quality of my question. I feel properly chagrined, as I should know better than to submit something without first reading the documentation. Regardless of whether or not there are any more answers to this question, I've edited it in a way that I hope makes it an at least somewhat better submission, in an attempt to be a better member of the community.

Comment: @tchrist, can I ask what you mean by naming things in programs and how you feel it applies to this question? I want to understand so that I do not make the same mistake again.

Comment: @AndrewZito Our [Help Center says: *But please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site. ... **Naming, including naming programming variables/classes.***](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) This therefore includes database `enum` values.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure I agree that this is a question about "naming" as distinct from the sense in which any word "names" a concept -- but thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: @tchrist♦: The question has been edited such as to have no more references to computer code (although I would be inclined to say it was never really asking for the name of a variable, but rather for a word that such a name could possibly be based off, so I wouldn't say it was off topic for that reason). Do you think it could be reopened now? It is also much improved in other respects.

Comment: @AndrewZito: Don't worry. This site is just grumpy owing to the flood of single-word requests we receive (and to the fact that only 5 high-rep users are needed to close a question, and only one to complain about it, which numbers are very easy to achieve on a bigger SE website such as this one). But your dealing with that has been exemplary!

Comment: @Cerberus Agreed.

Comment: @tchrist♦: Yay.

Answer (score 6):

**[sporadic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sporadic)**: occurring occasionally, singly, or in irregular or random instances

**[infrequent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infrequent)**: seldom happening or occurring, placed or occurring at wide intervals in space or time

<sub>Definitions from, and links to, Merriam-Webster</sub>

Comment: Thank you! This is an excellent suggestion. It doesn't quite match what I am envisioning for reasons I added to the main question: "I feel that this fails to capture the purposefulness that might be present, and instead implies a level of external chaos (like, if purchases just appear on your shopping list at random). I also perceive a connotation of scarcity in the term 'sporadic'." But of course I understand that others might disagree, and I thank you for providing your input.